# Select string till first or second space in string

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have table column that contains in each row data like this:

```
|                 Simbols              |
|--------------------------------------|
|H412 Text text                        |
|H413 Text text text text              |
|EUH 001 Text text text text text text |
|EUH 006 text text                     |
|EUH 201/201A Text text. Text text     |
```

And I need from that data get data like this:

```
|Simbols     |
|------------|
|H412        |
|H413        |
|EUH 001     |
|EUH 006     |
|EUH 201/201A|
```

I tried with SUBSTRING and CHARINDEX but it till the end don't work... It takes only first space or something like that...
QUERY:

```
SELECT 
CASE 
    WHEN SUBSTRING(Simbols, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', Simbols)) = ''
    THEN Simbols + ' '
    ELSE SUBSTRING(Simbols, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', Simbols))
END 'Simbols'
FROM dbo.table
```

RESULT:

```
|  Simbols   |
|------------|
|H412        |
|H413        |
|EUH         |
|EUH         |
|EUH         |
```

How can I make this work, and where is the problem?
Maybe there is different way to get these Simbols? 
P.S. "Text text text" is a example, there comes a explanations of "Simbols"

Comment: If it is up to the second space then why are the first 2 in your desired results stopping at the first?

Comment: @ASPFox Do you want to remove the character TEXT from each row and display the remaining?

Comment: Try Regular Expressions as answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826/how-to-do-a-regular-expression-replace-in-mysql

Comment: That "Text" is only a example, there is different text!

Answer (score 7):

[The `CharIndex()` function](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx) has an optional 3rd parameter - `start_location` - that will be key here.

```
SELECT your_column
     , CharIndex(' ', your_column) As first_space
     , CharIndex(' ', your_column, CharIndex(' ', your_column) + 1) As second_space
     , SubString(your_column, 1, CharIndex(' ', your_column, CharIndex(' ', your_column) + 1)) As first_two_words
FROM   your_table
```

Unfortunately when the `CharIndex()` function can't find the specified string (in this case a single space `' '`) it will return 0 (zero).

This means that if there isn't a first or second space the result of `first_two_words` in my above example will return an empty string as `SubString(your_column, 1, 0) = ''`.

To get around this you need to be a little clever.

Essentially, if `second_space = 0` then we need to return the full string. We have a few options for this:

```
SELECT your_column
     , CharIndex(' ', your_column) As first_space
     , CharIndex(' ', your_column, CharIndex(' ', your_column) + 1) As second_space
     , SubString(your_column, 1, CharIndex(' ', your_column, CharIndex(' ', your_column) + 1)) As first_two_words
     , SubString(your_column, 1, Coalesce(NullIf(CharIndex(' ', your_column, CharIndex(' ', your_column) + 1), 0), Len(your_column))) As first_two_words_option1
     , CASE WHEN CharIndex(' ', your_column, CharIndex(' ', your_column) + 1) = 0 THEN your_column ELSE SubString(your_column, 1, CharIndex(' ', your_column, CharIndex(' ', your_column) + 1)) END As first_two_words_option2
FROM   (
        SELECT 'one' As your_column
        UNION ALL SELECT 'one two'
        UNION ALL SELECT 'one two three'
        UNION ALL SELECT 'one two three four'
       ) As x
```

Comment: Very close "first_two_words_option1" and "first_two_words_option2" but still takes first text from "H412" Symbol column :(

Comment: @ASPFox correct. This query answers your question title "Select string till second space in string". You did not respond to my comment on your question so I will ask you here again: "If it is up to the second space then why are the first 2 in your desired results stopping at the first?". Without you telling us **why** these cases are different we can't provide answers.

Comment: Sorry for that! question title is little confusing and sorry about that too. But in description I gave a example of results what I need an where is the problem! There is many type of Simbols and explanations of these Simbols in DB in one row like "H412 Text text" or "EUH 201/201A Text text. Text text" this is the Simbol "H412" or "EUH 201/201A" and Simbols explanations is "Text text", did I answered on your question? :)

Comment: @ASPFox No, I'm afraid that doesn't answer the question. What **rule** is required to determine whether the first space or second space is the one you want to use?

Comment: @ASPFox I've had a guess at your real requirements. Does the following query work for you? http://pastebin.com/ArDjgd4P

Comment: OK! Forget about spaces, forget it! I need only "H412", "EUH 201/201A" etc Simbols. Not that "Text" It is possible or not? Thanks, and sorry about that misunderstanding question title, I admit it's incorrect, and I don't know what else to call this question, sorry! :/

Comment: @ASPFox have you tried the code I posted a link to in my last comment?

Answer (score 1):

Try this: It works

```
SELECT CASE WHEN charindex(' ', Simbols, charindex(' ', Simbols) + 1) = 0
THEN Simbols
ELSE LEFT(Simbols, charindex(' ', Simbols, charindex(' ', Simbols) + 1))
END
FROM dbo.table
```

Here is screenshot what I tried.
[image]

Here is new **EDIT**

```
SELECT REPLACE(Simbols, 'text', '') FROM dbo.table
```

Here is screen shot

[image]

Comment: Very close but still takes first text from "H412" Simbols column :(

Comment: Yes but look at 1 and 2 Simbol There is "Text", the point is that I don't need that "Text" I need only simbols "H412" "H413" "EUH 001" "EUH 006"... not "H412 Text" "H413 Text". Idea is not bad, very close, but there is something missing... :(

Comment: That "Text" is only a example, there is different text! Sorry for not mentioning that.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
select TRIM(REPLACE(lower(type),"text" ,"")) as T, type from supportContacts
```

Sql Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d5cf8/4

for more info :http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace