# Pulling text out of a string in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have been assigned with the task of getting part numbers out of a string in our database. I know that the part will be between the first and second comma in the string but I have no idea how to go about doing this. Any one have any suggestions? This is an example of the string I will be working with LEL,SPEC2078,14 CUT LEADS,#18 1/32

Comment: And what would be the result you want from that string?

Comment: did you even try to google this first?  "split string sql"

Comment: @ScottSelby +1 and: What have you tried so far?

Comment: perhaps you want to run a script to seperate the whole column of comma separated values and put them in necessary columns ??

Comment: I think you'll find my answer here useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21456821/select-string-till-first-or-second-space-in-string/21457036#21457036

Obviously you're looking at commas and not spaces but the same logic can be applied ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming the partno is in a column called p and the name of your table is products:

```
select SUBSTRING(p, charindex(',',p,1)+1, case when charindex(',',p,charindex(',',p,1)+1) = 0 then len(p)-charindex(',',p,1) else charindex(',',p,charindex(',',p,1)+1) end)
from products
```

Comment: Thank you very much I've never done anything like this in SQL so I wasn't  even sure how to really ask the question. This will get me started.

Answer (score 1):

No problem! Might be best to write a function if you have to do this for several different items inside a CSV string.

```
SELECT 'LEL,SPEC2078,14 CUT LEADS,#18 1/32'

SELECT SUBSTRING('LEL,SPEC2078,14 CUT LEADS,#18 1/32',1,CHARINDEX(',','LEL,SPEC2078,14 CUT LEADS,#18 1/32',1)-1) -- Get's the first value
SELECT SUBSTRING('LEL,SPEC2078,14 CUT LEADS,#18 1/32',CHARINDEX(',','LEL,SPEC2078,14 CUT LEADS,#18 1/32',2) + 1, CHARINDEX(',','LEL,SPEC2078,14 CUT LEADS,#18 1/32',2) + CHARINDEX(',','LEL,SPEC2078,14 CUT LEADS,#18 1/32',1)) -- Get's the next value
```

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use [Substring](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx) to pull out certain strings and [CharIndex](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx) to find the position of the commas.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your help this was my final solution.

```
select inm.fpartno, SUBSTRING(inm.fdescript, charindex(',',inm.fdescript,1)+1,
```

case when charindex(',',inm.fdescript,charindex(',',inm.fdescript,1)+1) = 0 
then len(inm.fdescript)-charindex(',',inm.fdescript,1) 
else CharIndex(',', inm.fdescript, CharIndex(',', inm.fdescript) + 1) - CharIndex(',', inm.fdescript) - 1 end)
from Database.dbo.inmast as inm`